# Terceiro eixo y gráfico python

Tags: python, gráfico

Eu estou precisando fazer um gráfico que tenha 3 eixos y. 1 no lado esquerdo e dois no direito. Eu estou conseguindo plotar eles, porém os do lado direito fica um em cima do outro. Como deixar do lado?

Segue a parte do código que ploto os gráficos:

```
IC_F = tabela['IC']
CGMAIS = tabela['+CG']
CGMENOS = tabela['-CG']

#Criando a figura
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
#Criando eixo
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#Criando outro eixo igual o ax
ax2 = ax.twinx()
#terceiro eixo
ax3 = ax.twinx()

ax2.plot(CGMENOS, color = 'blue', marker = 'o', lw =3, ls = '--', label = '-CG')
ax3.plot(CGMAIS, color = 'red', marker = 'o', lw =3, ls = '--', label = '+CG')
ax.plot(IC_F, color = 'black', marker = 'o', lw =3, ls = '--', label = 'IC')

ax.set_xlabel('Hora Local')
ax.set_ylabel('Relâmpagos IC (ocorrências/hora)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Relâmpagos -CG (ocorrências/hora)')
ax3.set_ylabel('Relâmpagos +CG (ocorrências/hora)')

ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0), useMathText=True)
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0), useMathText=True)
ax3.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0), useMathText=True)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,24,1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,70000,10000))
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(0,6000,1000))
ax3.set_yticks(np.arange(0,300,50))

fig.legend(loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(.78,.88))

plt.title('Ciclo diurno relâmpagos BrasilDAT: novembro')
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona essa linha no seu código, logo após `ax3 = ax.twinx()`

```
ax3.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.07))
```

Ajuste o espaçamento se quiser deixar o eixo mais afastado ou mais colado do outro. Para saber mais, consulte [https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html#:~:text=set_position(position),zero%27%20-%3E%20(%27data%27%2C%200.0)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html#:%7E:text=set_position(position),zero%27%20-%3E%20(%27data%27%2C%200.0))

Comment: Muito obrigada!!!